# The area of four circles at the origin intersecting

Tags: geometry

The problem asks:

[image: Problem]

I don't even know where to start. Do I need to find the width of the shaded areas, or something else completely?

**UPDATE**: Using the information given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289336/how-do-i-find-the-area-of-this-region), I was able to act as if the circles were inside of a square and use those methods.

Thank You

Comment: Hint: draw some sectors, and find the area of the curvy bit.

Comment: see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289336)

Comment: By symmetry, integrate in polar coordinates from $0$ to $\pi/4$, then multiply by 8. The polar equation of the uppermost circle is $r=a\sin\theta$ for a circle of radius $a$.

Comment: @achillehui, Thank You, I didn't realize those methods would be applicable here.